# Setting Parent State from Children Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have one parent and one child component.

Child component is basically a navigation bar. While Parent renders the navigation bar.

I would like to change parent state when click on the children component.

Parent Constructor

```
   constructor(props) {
      super(props); // Must call
      this.state = {show: "login", user: "guest"};
}

 render() {
 contents = <><Menu/><Activities /></>;
      return (
      contents
      );
}
```

Child Component

```
  constructor(props) {
      super(props); // Must call
      // a member variable called "state" to hold the state as a JS object
      this.state = {show: "login", user: "guest",
      };
 render() {
 contents =  contents = <ul>
            <li><a >Home</a></li>
            <li><a >Activities</a></li>
            <li><a >Membership</a></li>
            </ul>;

      return (
      contents
      );
}
```

Comment: you'll need to pass the `setState` of the parent to the child component.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [react js set state from parent to child component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48389653/react-js-set-state-from-parent-to-child-component)

Answer (score 0):

As in React, [the Data Flows Down](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#the-data-flows-down), for the child component to change state of its parent, it can only be done via callback passed the parent.

You can pass the callback via `props`, Context API, or use any state management library.

For example:

```
class App extends Component {
  state = { show: "login", user: "guest" };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Menu />
        <Activities onClick={this.setState} />
      </>
    );
  }
}

class App extends Component {
  state = { show: "login", user: "guest" };

  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        <li onClick={() => this.props.onClick({ show: "Home" })}>
          <a>Home</a>
        </li>
        <li onClick={() => this.props.onClick({ show: "Activities" })}>
          <a>Activities</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
```